# does using objects as map keys in dart can have significant performance impact?

Tags: performance, dictionary, dart, benchmarking

Writing some code in dart I found recently a case when it is simpler to use certain objects as map keys. Actually this code is executed in web mode (compiled to javascript) but eventually it will be used also in dart VM  mode.

Does using objects as keys of map can have significant memory / performance impact in dart?

I didn't found a lot of resources on benchmarking that (https://dart.dev/articles/benchmarking is defunct), so any directions are also welcome.

Answer (score 7):

There are some considerations:

#### Memory

Since each object used as keys will be refereed by the Map, each object cannot be garbage collected unless the `Map` itself can be garbage collected or the key has been removed from the `Map`. The same can be said for the associated value for each key.

As of storage used by the Map for keeping the keys and values, it should not make any difference at all if you are using e.g. `String` as a key or a custom object since both kind of keys will just be saved as references.

#### Performance

The performance of operations on a `Map` are very much a question about the performance of the `==` operator and `hashCode` property since both are used for several of the operations used on a `Map`.

I can recommend reading about them here:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html

#### Conclusion

A lot of projects are using custom objects as keys for Maps and usually there are no problems of during that. In fact, using a custom object are no more different than using e.g. a `String` as key since `String` are also just a normal class with its own `==` operator and `hashCode` property.